# Obtain the total of a condition in the same query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a query, which consists of get a percentage. Here is the structure of the tables:

STransaction:

```
TRANSACTIONID -> NUMBER(10,0)
TRANSACTIONMONTH -> VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
CUSTOMER_CUSTOMERID -> NUMBER(8,0)
COMMERCIALDESCRIPTION -> VARCHAR2(500 BYTE)
AMOUNTTM -> NUMBER(8,2)
AMOUNTDESCRIPTION -> VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
FOB -> NUMBER(10,2)
FOBUNIT -> NUMBER(10,2)
CFR -> NUMBER(10,2)
CFRUNIT -> NUMBER(10,2)
SUPPLIER_SUPPLIERID -> NUMBER(8,0)
BOARDINGCOUNTRY -> VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
BOARDINDBAY -> VARCHAR2(400 BYTE)
TRANSPORTATIONVIA -> VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
CUSTOMS -> VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
TRANSACTIONYEAR -> VARCHAR2(4 BYTE)
TRANSACTIONDAY  -> VARCHAR2(2 BYTE)
CHAPTER -> VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)
TARIFFHEADING -> NUMBER(12,0)
PRODUCTFAMILY_PRODUCTFAMILYID -> NUMBER(5,0)
```

Customer:

```
CUSTOMERID -> NUMBER(8,0)
CUSTOMERNAME -> VARCHAR2(80 BYTE)
COUNTRY_COUNTRYID -> NUMBER(5,0)
ISVDT -> CHAR(1 BYTE)
```

Supplier:

```
SUPPLIERID -> NUMBER(8,0)
SUPPLIERNAME -> VARCHAR2(80 BYTE)
SUPPLIERCOUNTRY -> VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
```

ProductFamily:

```
PRODUCTFAMILYID -> NUMBER(5,0)
PRODFAMNAME -> VARCHAR2(60 BYTE)
```

Country:

```
COUNTRYID -> NUMBER(5,0)
COUNTRYNAME -> VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
REGION_REGIONID -> NUMBER(5,0)
COUNTRYABBR -> VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)
```

I need to make a table that for each year obtains the percentage of sales of each customer, which is represented by the CFR column in the STRANSACTION table. In the code below, I have a query that gets the sales of each customer in each year:

```
SELECT cus.customername c, 
SUM(CASE WHEN tran.transactionyear = 2013 THEN tran.cfr ELSE 0 END) 2013,
SUM(CASE WHEN tran.transactionyear = 2014 THEN tran.cfr ELSE 0 END) 2014,
SUM(CASE WHEN tran.transactionyear = 2015 THEN tran.cfr ELSE 0 END) 2015,
SUM(CASE WHEN tran.transactionyear = 2016 THEN tran.cfr ELSE 0 END) 2016,
SUM(CASE WHEN tran.transactionyear = 2017 THEN tran.cfr ELSE 0 END) 2017
FROM Stransaction tran, Customer cus, Productfamily family, Country country 
WHERE tran.customer_customerid = cus.customerid AND cus.country_countryid = country.countryid
AND tran.productfamily_productfamilyid = family.productfamilyid AND country.countryname = 'Germany'
AND tran.transactionyear > 2012 AND tran.transactionyear < 2018 AND family.prodfamname = 'Bond-offset Paper'
GROUP BY (cus.customername);
```

The percentage must be obtained from the total sales of all customers for each year. Example, the percentage of sales of customer 1 for the year 2014 is equal to the sales of customer 1 of year 2014 on the total sales of all customers of 2014. Finally you should see a table like the following:

C = Customer && 1 = CustomerName

```
C|  2013 |   %   |  2014 |   %   |  2015 |   %   |  2016 |   %   | 2017 |
 |-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|------|
1|165.250|100,00%|152.336|100,00%|136.540|100,00%|121.533|100,00%|80.345|
```

How I can get the totals in the same query? I tested functions like OVER but this function is applied on all data (and the data is of all years and not of a specific year -> Due to WHERE applied).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be rather simple. You get a sum over all records with `SUM(value) OVER ()`. Hence:

```
SELECT
  c,
  "2013", ROUND("2013" * 100 / SUM("2013") OVER(), 2) AS "2013 %",
  "2014", ROUND("2014" * 100 / SUM("2014") OVER(), 2) AS "2014 %",
  "2015", ROUND("2015" * 100 / SUM("2015") OVER(), 2) AS "2015 %",
  "2016", ROUND("2016" * 100 / SUM("2016") OVER(), 2) AS "2016 %",
  "2017", ROUND("2017" * 100 / SUM("2017") OVER(), 2) AS "2017 %"
FROM
(
  SELECT cus.customername c, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN tran.transactionyear = 2013 THEN tran.cfr ELSE 0 END) AS "2013",
    SUM(CASE WHEN tran.transactionyear = 2014 THEN tran.cfr ELSE 0 END) AS "2014",
    SUM(CASE WHEN tran.transactionyear = 2015 THEN tran.cfr ELSE 0 END) AS "2015",
    SUM(CASE WHEN tran.transactionyear = 2016 THEN tran.cfr ELSE 0 END) AS "2016",
    SUM(CASE WHEN tran.transactionyear = 2017 THEN tran.cfr ELSE 0 END) AS "2017"
  FROM Stransaction tran, 
  JOIN Customer cus ON tran.customer_customerid = cus.customerid
  WHERE tran.transactionyear BETWEEN 2013 AND 2017
    AND cus.country_countryid = 
        (SELECT countryid FROM Country WHERE countryname = 'Germany')
    AND tran.productfamily_productfamilyid = 
        (SELECT productfamilyid FROM Productfamily WHERE prodfamname = 'Bond-offset Paper')
  GROUP BY (cus.customername)
)
ORDER BY c;
```

I've changed your old comma-separated joins to modern ANSI standard (well "modern" since 1992 that is) and only joined the tables you want to see results from. Conditions such as on country and product family belong in the `WHERE` clause in my opinion (or in the `ON` clause if you want so). 2013 etc. being numbers are no valid alias names; you should use quotes hence: "2013".

Comment: Thanks, I'm amazed at the quality of the answer and it actually works. I wanted to ask you if know of a good book to learn this new standard or if you recommend me to search in internet. @ThorstenKettner

Comment: No, sorry, I have no recommendation. I have been using SQL some twenty years and mainly learn from Google and SO now. But this is no general recommendation. I have seen w3schools and would definitely not recommend that, but I have no other recommendation either.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you need all transactions sum in every year without customer
i think you can do(calculate and execute  select ) it by `pl/sql language` with tempererory table procedure, but if you want to use only `sql` you should use `cte` for example like this

```
with cte as (select cus.customername,tran.transactionyear,tran.cfr
  from Stransaction tran, Customer cus, Productfamily family, Country country
 where tran.customer_customerid = cus.customerid
   and cus.country_countryid = country.countryid
   and tran.productfamily_productfamilyid = family.productfamilyid
   and country.countryname = 'Germany'
   and tran.transactionyear > 2012
   and tran.transactionyear < 2018
   and family.prodfamname = 'Bond-offset Paper'
)


select sel1.customername c,
       sel1.year2013,
       sel1.year2013 * 100/ sel2.year2013 perc2013,
       sel1.year2014,
       sel1.year2014 * 100/ sel2.year2014 perc2014,
       sel1.year2015,
       sel1.year2015 * 100/ sel2.year2015 perc2015,
       sel1.year2016,
       sel1.year2016 * 100/ sel2.year2016 perc2016,
       sel1.year2017,
       sel1.year2017 * 100/ sel2.year2017 perc2017
 from 
(select cte1.customername,
       sum(decode(cte1.transactionyear,2013,cte1.cfr,0)) year2013,
       sum(decode(cte1.transactionyear,2014,cte1.cfr,0)) year2014,
       sum(decode(cte1.transactionyear,2015,cte1.cfr,0)) year2015,
       sum(decode(cte1.transactionyear,2016,cte1.cfr,0)) year2016,
       sum(decode(cte1.transactionyear,2017,cte1.cfr,0)) year2017
  from cte cte1
 group by (cte1.customername)) sel1, 
 (select sum(decode(cte2.transactionyear,2013,cte2.cfr,0)) year2013,
       sum(decode(cte2.transactionyear,2014,cte2.cfr,0)) year2014,
       sum(decode(cte2.transactionyear,2015,cte2.cfr,0)) year2015,
       sum(decode(cte2.transactionyear,2016,cte2.cfr,0)) year2016,
       sum(decode(cte2.transactionyear,2017,cte2.cfr,0)) year2017
  from cte cte2
) sel2
```

Comment: That's right, but I think the query, which I marked as correct, is faster and easier to maintain